# Binding variable with TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have my XAML code (inside a `Page` of the standard blank page template) as

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock x:Name="tbBindingBlock">
</Grid>
```

And I have an `int` named `iTestBinding`in the code-behind. Is there a simple (since I'm only binding one variable and not a collection) way of binding the two together so that the latest value of `iTestBinding` (which keeps getting changed from the code-behind) is always displayed inside `tbBindingBlock` ?

---

**Edit** : The code behind is pretty short :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public int iTestBinding=0;
```

Comment: Please see the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind your value directly using the below code

```
<TextBlock x:Name="tbBindingBlock" Text="{Binding iTestBinding}">
```

keep your value to bind as a property in code behind like this

```
      public int iTestBinding{ get; set; }
```

and set the datacontext in page loaded event like this

```
      this.DataContext = this;
```

if you want to update the value on button click and to be reflected in UI, you need to implement the PropertyChangedEventHandler.

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // take a copy to prevent thread issues
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

call RaisePropertyChanged("changed property name") where-ever you updated the value of the property.

Its better to keep a custom get set for the property so that we can call this method from the setter.for example

```
    private string myText;
    public string MyText { 
        get {
            return myText;
    }
        set {
            myText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyText");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What would the datacontext be set to in this case ?

Comment: may be you can set iTestBinding as the data context if there is no other bindings in your page.

Comment: Yes I tried that but nothing shows up on the page (the textblock shows up empty).

Comment: Yes I edited the question. There's nothing else in the code behind (there's just some code to increase the variable by + 1 when the user clicks a button).

Comment: It didn't (no text shows up in the textbox) but thank you for trying to help. I suspect it may have something to do with a difference in binding in Metro vs WPF.